# Adding multiple stylesheets to brunch

Tags: angularjs, stylesheet, brunch

I'm almost new to angular and I'm working on an Angular2 project.
I want to add these following css files to brunch
What is the syntax?
Is it better to add it to brunch-config.js or index.html?

Files:

> ```
> '/app/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
>
> '/app/assets/css/custom.css',
>
> '/app/assets/css/font-awesome.css',
>
> 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'
> ```

brunch-config.js:

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^node_modules/,
        'main.js': /^app/
      },
      order: {
        after: [/\.html$/, /\.css$/]
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: 'app.css'
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: 'main.js'
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    inlineCss: {
      html: true,
      passthrough: [/^node_modules/, 'app/global.css']
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import fonts using `@import` CSS at-rule or `<link>` HTML element, as usual. To add other files, put them to `app/styles` directory. The reason they are not used now is because they are in `assets` folder: please, place only static assets (e.g. templates) there. These files will be joined to `app.css`. Make sure you have linked stylesheet in HTML.

Also, you may find [this skeleton](https://github.com/colinbate/ng2-brunch) useful for bootstrapping Angular 2 apps.

Comment: When I add them to my index.html document I get this error: Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:3333/app.styles.map